# Upgraded docker but old configuration is running after reboot

Tags: ubuntu, docker, docker-compose

I upgraded my Docker install on my Ubuntu system the other day.  According to my docker version command I am on version 19.03.8 for the client and 18.09.9 on the server.  I had my original docker-compose.yml file and it was working under the original setup (can't remember versions).  I created a new configuration on a new compose file (the old one still exists). The problem is, when I try to `docker compose up` the file, I am told several ports are already in use.  Doing a `docker ps` shows me no running containers, but if I run `systemctl status docker.service` I can see all the containers from my original compose file up and running.  (I'll past it below).  What can I do to get these to stop so my new containers/config come up and run correctly?

````
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2020-05-04 01:01:00 UTC; 9min ago
     Docs: https://docs.docker.com
 Main PID: 1570 (dockerd)
    Tasks: 191
   CGroup: /system.slice/docker.service
           ├─1570 /usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock
           ├─2328 /usr/bin/docker-proxy -proto tcp -host-ip 0.0.0.0 -host-port 33400 -container-ip 172.18.0.2 -container-port 33400
           ├─2342 /usr/bin/docker-proxy -proto tcp -host-ip 0.0.0.0 -host-port 32469 -container-ip 172.18.0.2 -container-port 32469
           ├─2356 /usr/bin/docker-proxy -proto udp -host-ip 0.0.0.0 -host-port 32414 -container-ip 172.18.0.2 -container-port 32414
           ├─2370 /usr/bin/docker-proxy -proto udp -host-ip 0.0.0.0 -host-port 32413 -container-ip 172.18.0.2 -container-port 32413
           ├─2393 /usr/bin/docker-proxy -proto udp -host-ip 0.0.0.0 -host-port 32412 -container-ip 172.18.0.2 -container-port 32412
           ├─2405 /usr/bin/docker-proxy -proto udp -host-ip 0.0.0.0 -host-port 32410 -container-ip 172.18.0.2 -container-port 32410
           ├─2420 /usr/bin/docker-proxy -proto tcp -host-ip 0.0.0.0 -host-port 32400 -container-ip 172.18.0.2 -container-port 32400
           ├─2434 /usr/bin/docker-proxy -proto tcp -host-ip 0.0.0.0 -host-port 8324 -container-ip 172.18.0.2 -container-port 8324
           ├─2448 /usr/bin/docker-proxy -proto tcp -host-ip 0.0.0.0 -host-port 3005 -container-ip 172.18.0.2 -container-port 3005
           ├─2462 /usr/bin/docker-proxy -proto udp -host-ip 0.0.0.0 -host-port 1900 -container-ip 172.18.0.2 -container-port 1900
           ├─2476 /usr/bin/docker-proxy -proto tcp -host-ip 0.0.0.0 -host-port 4040 -container-ip 172.18.0.3 -container-port 4040
           ├─2652 /usr/bin/docker-proxy -proto tcp -host-ip 0.0.0.0 -host-port 3306 -container-ip 172.18.0.8 -container-port 3306
           ├─6226 /usr/bin/docker-proxy -proto tcp -host-ip 0.0.0.0 -host-port 9091 -container-ip 172.18.0.13 -container-port 9091
           ├─6443 /usr/bin/docker-proxy -proto tcp -host-ip 0.0.0.0 -host-port 8920 -container-ip 172.18.0.13 -container-port 8920
           ├─6457 /usr/bin/docker-proxy -proto tcp -host-ip 0.0.0.0 -host-port 8080 -container-ip 172.18.0.14 -container-port 8080
           ├─6473 /usr/bin/docker-proxy -proto tcp -host-ip 0.0.0.0 -host-port 8096 -container-ip 172.18.0.13 -container-port 8096
           ├─6485 /usr/bin/docker-proxy -proto tcp -host-ip 0.0.0.0 -host-port 443 -container-ip 172.18.0.14 -container-port 443
           └─6498 /usr/bin/docker-proxy -proto tcp -host-ip 0.0.0.0 -host-port 80 -container-ip 172.18.0.14 -container-port 80

May 04 01:00:54 media_server dockerd[1570]: time="2020-05-04T01:00:54.642848692Z" level=warning msg="Health check for container fde7ffb770ea235d2b21e7aa5c9550783827bd539c0937a707cb
May 04 01:00:55 media_server dockerd[1570]: time="2020-05-04T01:00:55.582611517Z" level=warning msg="Security options with `:` as a separator are deprecated and will be completely
May 04 01:00:55 media_server dockerd[1570]: time="2020-05-04T01:00:55.582814909Z" level=warning msg="Security options with `:` as a separator are deprecated and will be completely
May 04 01:00:55 media_server dockerd[1570]: time="2020-05-04T01:00:55.638352716Z" level=warning msg="Security options with `:` as a separator are deprecated and will be completely
May 04 01:00:57 media_server dockerd[1570]: time="2020-05-04T01:00:57.752351831Z" level=info msg="Loading containers: done."
May 04 01:01:00 media_server dockerd[1570]: time="2020-05-04T01:01:00.370749213Z" level=info msg="Docker daemon" commit=afacb8b7f0 graphdriver(s)=overlay2 version=19.03.8
May 04 01:01:00 media_server dockerd[1570]: time="2020-05-04T01:01:00.412157436Z" level=info msg="Daemon has completed initialization"
May 04 01:01:00 media_server dockerd[1570]: time="2020-05-04T01:01:00.544504808Z" level=info msg="API listen on /var/run/docker.sock"
May 04 01:01:00 media_server systemd[1]: Started Docker Application Container Engine.
May 04 01:01:01 media_server dockerd[1570]: time="2020-05-04T01:01:01.861407238Z" level=warning msg="Health check for container fde7ffb770ea235d2b21e7aa5c9550783827bd539c0937a707cb
r ```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
docker ps -a
```

shows stopped containers. You must

```
docker rm <container>
```

for each one prior to recreating it. Or

```
docker-compose down
```

from the directory with your docker-compose.yml to remove all the conainers from your project with one command

If you reboot with existing Docker containers (either running or stopped) they will be restored in that state after reboot

Comment: ```docker ps -a``` showed no containers either.

Comment: 1. `docker ps -a` empty 2. `systemctl restart docker` 3. `docker ps -a` still empty?

Comment: Now I am seeing them.  I will try and remove them one at a time.

Comment: `docker-compose down` takes care of all of them with one command

Comment: I know, I wanted to be 100% sure.  I had tried it before and it wasn't bringing them down.  Looks like I am ok now.  I archived my old docker-compose.yml and am running docker-compose up with the new one.  Pulling the images again ans should be up soon I hope.